# GDB set breakpoint in function offset

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, breakpoints, gdbserver

I can set breakpoint like

```
b some_function
```

But hiw can I put a breakpoint in offset 0x10 of this function

```
b some_function +0x10
```

Or
b (some_function +0x10)

Doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(gdb) p &foo
$1 = (<text variable, no debug info> *) 0x555555555129 <foo>
(gdb) b *foo+0x10
Breakpoint 2 at 0x555555555139
```

QED.

Comment: Please add context around code-only answers